# laravel create a database with mysql cl via SSH

Tags: mysql, laravel, ssh

Let me describe my setup a bit. I have a server in which there are several VMS. In one of those VMs I have a laravel application which will be creating instances of an eshop. Each time a new database must be created. So I am trying to connect to the server via SSH so I can create a new mysql database for the new eshop instance.

I have used laravelCollectives/remote to connect via SSH in the following way

```
SSH::run([
            'mysql --user=root --password="rootpassword"',
            'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO "myuser_1"@"localhost"',
            'create database test',
            'FLUSH PRIVILEGES'
        ]);
```

Although i get this message when i run this " mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure." which means I have probably connected to mysql, nothing happens.

I have tried sending only the command mkdir test to see if the SSH connection is ok and the folder is created successfully, which means the SSH connection is fine. But for some reason I cant create a new database. I tried deleting a database since its only the mysql connection command and the drop command instead of all of the above but still nothing.

Any ideas would be valuable!

/************ EDIT *************/
As per your suggestion i tried

```
SSH::run([
            "mysql --user=root --password='pass'",
            "CREATE USER 'test_user_1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass2'",
            "create database test",
            "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'test_user_1'@'localhost'",
            "FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
        ]);
```

When i tried using ; at the end of each line an error was produced. I guess the ; is added automatically by the laravelCollectives/remote lib. When i try to use the exact same commands on the servers terminal the database is being created. Am i doing something wrong with the remote lib???

Comment: Did you try putting the `;` at the end of each MySQL Statement?

Comment: I would also try moving the `Flush` up one so it is done after the `Grant`